# How exactly does Phrenic Strike Work?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, ardent

In DnD 4e there's an *Encounter Power* called *Phrenic Strike*.

The flavour text reads:

> *You fight past your enemy's attack to deliver a punishing blow to its body and mind.*

The Effect says:

> **Before** the attack, you shift 1 square.

Which is followed by an attack.

**BUT**, the Trigger says:

> An enemy **hits** you **with a melee attack**

I see there to be some contradiction: The enemy needs to hit me in order to trigger the power, but the Effect says that I shift before the attack? So will he still do damage or won't he?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an **Immediate Reaction**, Phrenic Strike takes place after the trigger occurs.

Therefore, the Hit that triggered the attack would complete (meaning you take the damage and any other effects), before you are able to shift from Phrenic Strike.

Note that "The attack" specified in the effect of Phrenic Strike is the attack Phrenic Strike is going to make, not the attack you are being hit with. If it was the latter, it probably would be written as "The triggering attack" to disambiguate it.

Comment: You may want to specifically note that "the attack" the effect line refers to is the attack you are about to make, not that attack the enemy hits you with in the trigger line.